# Remove lines in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been developing this graphic in R using ggplot2 for a few days now.  I am almost done but I am having a problem.
[image: Enter image description here.]

I have no idea how to get rid of those lines that keep crossing over.  From what I can see, they are connecting the last point of a color to the next point that is that same color.  It's not a problem for colors that do not repeat in the graph, but for the ones that do it does.

Here's what my script looks like:

```
section <- factor(p04_NoNegative$GS_Field, c("Out of Bounds", "High Weeds","Short Hieght","Low Thin",
        "Low Weeds","High Thin","Down","High Moisture","Medium Thin","Tall Hieght","Medium Weeds","Clumping","Low Moisture"))

x_axis_ef <- seq(0,6000,500)

#Speed
ggplot(p04_NoNegative, aes(x=Distance.Traveled, y=GS_VehicleSpeed)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = section, group = section)) + 
  ggtitle("p04 entire field") + ylim(0,3) +
  ylab("Speed (m/s)")+ xlab("Distance (m)") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_axis_ef) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,5000))
```

All of the colored areas of the graphs have a factor value in the `section` vector.  The gray areas in the graph have no factor value and are showed as `<NA>` when I view the vector.

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: it looks to me like you forgot to specify `group = section` in `geom_line(aes(color = section, group = section))` at least thats what it looks like to me but hard  to tell

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't change anything.  I've only been doing R for a few days now so my code isn't always the easiest and most efficient method.

Comment: what happens when you drop `group=section`?

Comment: Nothing.  I've ran it both ways and the graph is no different.

Comment: Make a reproducible post. Use a small sample of your data and post the output of `dput` on the sample

Comment: I'm not sure how well I'll be able to do that.  The data set I'm using has roughly 350,000 lines of data.  I'm working on one now though.

Comment: `geom_line(aes(colour=section, group=1)) `